# How to implement class derived from templated class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, templates, linker-errors

I have solution with 2 projects inside. In first project which is builded as library I have templated class

**a.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

template<class MessageType, class HandlerType>
class A
{
    std::unique_ptr<MessageType> msg;
    std::unique_ptr<HandlerType> handler;
public:
    A() : msg(std::make_unique<MessageType>()), handler(std::make_unique<HandlerType>()) {}
    virtual ~A() {}
};
```

Then derived class

**b.h**

```
#include "a.h"
#include <string>

struct MyMessage
{};
struct MyHandler
{};
class B : A<MyMessage, MyHandler>
{
    std::string name;
public:
    B(const std::string& str);
    virtual ~B();
};
```

and implementing it

**b.cpp**

```
#include "b.h"

B::B(const std::string& str)
{
}

B::~B()
{}
```

This code builded as static library (.lib). But when I try in main project to use instance of B class:

**process.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    B opa("yes");
}
```

compiler can't link it

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ConsoleApplication3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>b.cpp
1>ConsoleApplication3.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>ConsoleApplication3.vcxproj -> C:\Users\user\source\repos\tmpClass\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.lib
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: tmpClass, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>process.cpp
2>process.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall B::B(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0B@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function _main
2>process.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall B::~B(void)" (??1B@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
2>C:\Users\user\source\repos\tmpClass\Debug\tmpClass.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
2>Done building project "tmpClass.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: It looks like the issue here is only about how you compile multiple files; the template has nothing to do with the problem. Apparently there's a file named `process.cpp` that gets compiled to produce `process.obj`, and there's no mention of `b.cpp` or `b.obj` in the output you've shown. Have you successfully written projects that involve more than one source file before? (Note: don't `#include "b.cpp"` anywhere; that's not the right solution)

Comment: I just show example because I can't attach the whole project. But if I do implement B class inside header class without b.cpp then all is ok.

Comment: You haven't added `b.cpp` to your project. It's not being compiled, or at least not linked with.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Your project consists of (at least) two source files, `process.cpp` and `b.cpp`. The error message looks like it's saying that only one of them is being linked. If that's right, the problem is in the setup of the project and not in the code.

Comment: it is exists and compiled. a.h, b.h and b.cpp exists in separate project in solution and compiled as library. But in process.cpp I use that B class.

Comment: I did add more info to understand the problem.

Comment: @Pasha The program works(compiles) successfully. What command did you use to compile your program? And which compiler and OS are you using? You need to also compile `b.cpp`.

Comment: In tags I specified VS: ```visual studio 2019 (v142)```, ```/std:c++17```. Static lib compiled well. Full logs updated.

Answer (score 0):

LNK2019 means that the corresponding lib file is not added. You need to add the Lib file directory in **Properties>Linker>General>Additional Library Directories** and add Lib file in **Properties>Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies**.
Please refer to the document: [Use the functionality from the static library in the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160#UseLibInApp).